# List only per-workspace-enabled extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code lets you enable extensions for a specific workspace, using the "Enable (Workspace)" command.

Is there a way to list such extensions that I've specifically enabled in a workspace, without all my globally-enabled extensions?

I tried searching for `@enabled` in the extension sidebar, but this lists the globally and workspace enabled extensions all jumbled together in a single list.

Comment: go to the extension bar and the disabled extensions are grey

Comment: @rioV8 The issue isn't the disabled extensions, it's the extensions that are enabled *globally*. I'm only interested in the per-workspace-enabled extensions.

Comment: For reference, the filters like `@enabled` are documented here: [Extensions view filters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_extensions-view-filters), but there isn't one for "workspace enabled".

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to install and enable workspace extensions in VSCode with the .vscode folder?](/q/59529463/4518341) and [How to set which extensions are enabled when opening a new folder or workspace?](/q/54917413/4518341) Based on these, the list of enabled/disabled extensions for a workspace isn't stored in the workspace itself, so that's good to know at least.

Comment: Related: [Where does Visual Studio Code store information about enabled extensions per workspace?](/q/57760451/4518341) and [Where does VSCode store the enabled/disabled state for extensions?](/q/69706490/4518341) It looks like you can query the SQLite files.